# PHP-FPM Always Returns 200 Regardless Of NGINX Status Code

Tags: php, nginx, http-status

I have a PHP-based error page configuration with NGINX and PHP-FPM. However, when I request, for example, `example.com/nothing` (non-existent page), PHP-FPM returns a 200 status code, and not the correct 404 status code that NGINX returns. This also happens with other errors (ex: `example.com/assets` returning 200 with PHP-FPM when the status is 403 with NGINX). Essentially what I want PHP-FPM to do is mirror the status code shown by NGINX (override the 200 status code with the one shown by NGINX), so my error pages show the correct information. I am aware that you can change the status code by specifying it when using `http_response_code();`, but I would rather have the server do this without having me hard-code the proper status code.

Error page: `<? echo http_response_code(); ?>`

NGINX error page config:

```
set $errorDocs "/var/www/GLOBAL_RESOURCES/error";
recursive_error_pages on;
location ^~ $errorDocs {
  internal;
  alias $errorDocs;
}
#Resolve error asset location 404s
location /errorAssets {
  root $errorDocs;
}
error_page 404 /404.php;
location = /404.php {
  root $errorDocs;
  include /etc/nginx/xenon-conf/headers/fpm-params.conf;
}
```

PHP-FPM settings:

```
include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
proxy_intercept_errors on;
try_files $uri =404; 
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
fastcgi_index index.php;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

Fast-CGI Config:

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
#fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

Website Config:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com www.example.com;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.access.log;
  include /etc/nginx/xenon-conf/headers/php-fpm-enable.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/xenon-conf/headers/master-failover.conf;

  set $webRoot "/var/www/example.com";
  root $webRoot;
}
```

NGINX Config:

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
  log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

  access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

  sendfile            on;
  tcp_nopush          on;
  tcp_nodelay         on;
  keepalive_timeout   65;
  types_hash_max_size 4096;

  include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type        application/octet-stream;

  # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
  # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
  # for more information.
  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

  ### CUSTOM HTTP SERVER MASS IMPORTS ###
  include /etc/nginx/xenon-conf/websites/*.web;
  include /etc/nginx/xenon-conf/mapping/*.map;
}

### CUSTOM GENERIC STREAM MASS IMPORTS ###
include /etc/nginx/xenon-conf/stream/*.conf;
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

If nginx is detecting output from the FastCGI upstream it will
consider it as a valid response, even if the upstream (in this case,
php-fpm) triggered an error.

Disabling `display_errors` in the PHP-FPM pool fixes this.

`php_admin_value[display_errors] = Off` It prevents the PHP-script from
 showing error output to the screen, which in turn causes nginx to
 correctly throw an HTTP 500 Internal Server Error.

```
$  curl -i localhost:8080/test.php?time=`date +%s` HTTP/1.1 500
Internal Server Error Server: nginx ...
```

(no output is shown, empty response) You can still log all errors to a
 file, with the error_log directive.

```
php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/php-fpm/error.log
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
```

-- [Source](https://ma.ttias.be/nginx-sets-http-200-ok-php-fpm-parse-errors/)

In order to pass HTTP status codes from nginx to PHP-FPM, you also need to  put the following in your PHP handling location:

```
fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
```

According to the [manual](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_intercept_errors), this directive:

> Determines whether FastCGI server responses with codes greater than or equal to 300 should be passed to a client or be intercepted and redirected to nginx for processing with the error_page directive.

Comment: The scenario you described already works with my configuration. The problem I am having occurs on error pages displayed for 40x errors, which are client-side errors. PHP-FPM has no errors when running in this instance, so it returns 200, but I want it to mirror the status code shown by NGINX.

Comment: My configuration already had ``fastcgi_intercept_errors on;`` set. The PHP-FPM settings I gave are imported to the error page configuration for each PHP file. Even after adding the similar ``proxy_intercept_errors`` option, it still doesn't work.

Comment: In that case, please post your whole configuration file so I can try to reproduce the error.

Comment: The original question has been updated with the missing configs

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here is that by default `php-fpm` does not return status code to
`nginx` when exception occurs and `display_errors` is enabled.

### TLDR

Use some global error handler that set error status code like this:

```php
http_response_code(500);
```

This will be passed from `php-fpm` to `nginx` and attached to `nginx` response.

### How to test this behaviour

#### Create `index.php` file:

```php
<?php
// report all errors
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// do not display errors
ini_set("display_errors", 0);

// set http response code
// http_response_code(500);

// throw exception
throw new \Exception('TEST UNHANDLED EXCEPTION STATUS CODE');
```

#### Create `default.conf` for `nginx`

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root   /var/www/html;
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on php:9000
    location ~ \.php$ {
        root           /var/www/html;
        fastcgi_pass   php:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /var/www/html/$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

#### Create `docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: "3.5"

services:
  php:
    image: php:fpm
    volumes:
      - ./index.php:/var/www/html/index.php

  nginx:
    depends_on:
      - php
    image: nginx:latest
    volumes:
      - ./index.php:/var/www/html/index.php
      - ./default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

#### Run project

```sh
docker-compose up -d
```

#### Install additional tools for testing php-fpm inside `php` container

To test direct responses from `php-fpm` wee need to install `cgi-fcgi` binary

```sh
docker-compose exec php bash -c 'apt update && apt install -y libfcgi0ldbl'
```

#### Test responses with `display_errors` disabled

1. Inside `php` container, make direct request to `php-fpm`

   ```sh
   SCRIPT_NAME=/var/www/html/index.php SCRIPT_FILENAME=/var/www/html/index.php REQUEST_METHOD=GET cgi-fcgi -bind -connect localhost:9000
   ```
2. Response contains status code 500 that is handled by `nginx` correctly:

   ```
   Status: 500 Internal Server Error
   X-Powered-By: PHP/8.0.2
   Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
   ```
3. Test response from `nginx`

   ```sh
   docker-compose exec nginx curl -i localhost
   ```

   Response:

   ```
   HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
   Server: nginx/1.19.6
   Date: Mon, 22 Feb 2021 11:45:56 GMT
   Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
   Transfer-Encoding: chunked
   Connection: keep-alive
   X-Powered-By: PHP/8.0.2
   ```

`php-fpm` response contains status code 500 and has no body. `Nginx` use this code in response.

#### Test responses with `display_errors` enabled

1. Let's enable `display_errors` in `index.php`:

   ```php
   // do not display errors
   ini_set("display_errors", 1);
   ```
2. Inside `php` container, make direct request to `php-fpm`

   ```sh
   SCRIPT_NAME=/var/www/html/index.php SCRIPT_FILENAME=/var/www/html/index.php REQUEST_METHOD=GET cgi-fcgi -bind -connect localhost:9000
   ```

   Response:

   ```
   X-Powered-By: PHP/8.0.2
   Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

   <br />
   <b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Exception: TEST UNHANDLED EXCEPTION STATUS CODE in /var/www/html/index.php:12
   Stack trace:
   #0 {main}
     thrown in <b>/var/www/html/index.php</b> on line <b>12</b><br />
   ```
3. Test response from `nginx`

   ```sh
   docker-compose exec nginx curl -i localhost
   ```

   Response

   ```
   HTTP/1.1 200 OK
   Server: nginx/1.19.6
   Date: Mon, 22 Feb 2021 11:47:29 GMT
   Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
   Transfer-Encoding: chunked
   Connection: keep-alive
   X-Powered-By: PHP/8.0.2

   <br />
   <b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Exception: TEST UNHANDLED EXCEPTION STATUS CODE in /var/www/html/index.php:12
   Stack trace:
   #0 {main}
     thrown in <b>/var/www/html/index.php</b> on line <b>12</b><br />
   ```

`php-fpm` response is missing status code `500` but has a body. `Nginx` treats this as normal response
with status 200.

#### Test responses with `display_errors` enabled and header explicitly set to 500

1. Let's explicitly set response status code with `display_errors` on.

   ```php
   // set http response code
   http_response_code(500);
   ```
2. Test `php-fpm` response:

   ```sh
   SCRIPT_NAME=/var/www/html/index.php SCRIPT_FILENAME=/var/www/html/index.php REQUEST_METHOD=GET cgi-fcgi -bind -connect localhost:9000
   ```

   Response:

   ```
   Status: 500 Internal Server Error
   X-Powered-By: PHP/8.0.2
   Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

   <br />
   <b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Exception: TEST UNHANDLED EXCEPTION STATUS CODE in /var/www/html/index.php:12
   Stack trace:
   #0 {main}
     thrown in <b>/var/www/html/index.php</b> on line <b>12</b><br />
   ```
3. Test `Nginx` response

   ```sh
   docker-compose exec nginx curl -i localhost
   ```

   Response

   ```
   HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
   Server: nginx/1.19.6
   Date: Mon, 22 Feb 2021 11:52:38 GMT
   Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
   Transfer-Encoding: chunked
   Connection: keep-alive
   X-Powered-By: PHP/8.0.2

   <br />
   <b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Exception: TEST UNHANDLED EXCEPTION STATUS CODE in /var/www/html/index.php:12
   Stack trace:
   #0 {main}
     thrown in <b>/var/www/html/index.php</b> on line <b>12</b><br />
   ```

`php-fpm` response has status code `500` and body. `Nginx` uses body and status code from `php-fpm`.

### How to fix

A possible fix I can think of is global error handler that catch every unhandled error and
explicitly set proper error status code.